# Flow Builder Get Records Filter

Tags: visual-workflow

I need to get all of tomorrow's records in Flow Builder but I cannot make

```
{!$Flow.CurrentDate} +1
```

work as a condition.

Error message =

> We don't recognize that value. Make sure it's a valid date in this format: M/d/yyyy

Comment: did you create this as a formula element?

Comment: No. This should be a basic thing. Find records that occur tomorrow and set something up ready... like send an email to remind etc

Comment: If you are trying to use the new winter 20 schedule flows feature, then you are better off adding the filter in the flow itself.  The available options when you try to schedule from the start element are very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a flow:

[image]

The debug output from this:

[image]

and the trick is to use a formula resource called `Tomorrow` defined as: `{!$Flow.CurrentDate} + 1` that is the comparand in your Get Records filter

Comment: Elegent, thank you @cropredy